Cannot run AVD in Windows 10
ANDROID STUDIO :
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-232.10300.40.2321.11668458, built on April 4, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.9+0--11185874 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Registry:
    ide.experimental.ui=true

ERRORS ENCOUNTERED
The Code execution cannot proceed because libandroid-emu-metrics.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem

The Code execution cannot proceed because libandroid-emu-tracing.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem

The Code execution cannot proceed because libandroid-emu-protos.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem

The Code execution cannot proceed because libandroid-emu-agents.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem

The Code execution cannot proceed because libandroid-emu-curl.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem

I have tried uninstalling and installing android studio, also used the ladybug version but I'm experiencing the same error.
Contents of the directory
I already added the paths on my environment variables
User Variables

System Variables

This is my SDK Tools in my Android Studio


I also have this under extras in Sdk

My Device info

I'm really confused now, why that files are missing or not installed in the directory.

Does the following help? https://www.devopssupport.in/blog/solving-the-libandroid-emu-metrics-dll-not-found-error-in-android-development/

You appear to using an AMD processor. You can improve your post with the CPU model and PC RAM size. If your AMD based PC support virtualization you should use the "Windows Hypervisor Platform" See: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows-whpx and https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

@iNoob yes I have already checked that one but not able to resolve my issue

@MorrisonChang tried it but still not working, also added screenshot for CPU Model and  RAM.
